# Checkbox nas opções do tema

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

Estou criando uma *options page* para o meu tema no Wordpress, mas estou com uma certa dificuldade relacionada ao *checkbox*.

A ideia é a seguinte: Se o *checkbox* `infra_bloco1_visivel` estiver marcado ele vai habilitar uma `div` de conteúdo na página. Se estiver desmarcado, nada aparece.

Na *options page* o *checkbox* está assim:

```
$options[] = array(
    'name' => __('Bloco 1', 'options_check'),
    'desc' => __('Visível', 'options_check'),
    'id' => 'infra_bloco1_visivel',
    'std' => '1',
    'type' => 'checkbox');
```

A lógica será algo do tipo "Se 'infra_bloco1_visivel' estiver *checked*, mostre a DIV tal (ou qualquer outra coisa), caso não esteja *checked* não mostrar nada.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade a sua solução está em uma linguagem do lado cliente, no caso o javascript, segue uma solução que resolveria

http://jsfiddle.net/deFreitas/wsc7sot4/1/

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" checked="checked" />Marque para mostrar ou ocultar
<br />
<div class="conteudo">conteudo a ser mostrado</div>

<script>
    function mostrarOcultar(){
        if($(".checkbox").prop("checked"))
            $(".conteudo").show();
        else 
            $(".conteudo").hide();
    }

    $(function(){
        mostrarOcultar();
        $(".checkbox").click(mostrarOcultar);
    })

</script>
```